# Como criar uma expressão Lambda com Group by e Order By

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, expressões-lambda

Estou com problemas em criar um sentença Lambda com Group by e Order By Juntos.

Como agrupo pela coluna Escopo e IDEscopo, e ordenar pelo IDEscopo.

Segue Sentença.

```
 public static List<Escopos> EscoposCalCliente(int IDCalCLiente)
        {
            using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
            {
                return entidades.Escopos.Where(e => e.CALClientes.Any(cc => cc.IDCALCliente == IDCalCLiente)).
                ToList().
                GroupBy(es => new {.IDEscopo, es.IDEscopo }).
                SelectMany(esc => esc.OrderBy(escp => escp.IDEscopo));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Não vejo necessidade no seu exemplo de usar `GroupBy` e `OrderBy`. Apenas o `OrderBy` faz todo o trabalho.

```
    public static List<Escopos> EscoposCalCliente(int IDCalCLiente)
    {
        using (entidadesIUS entidades = new entidadesIUS())
        {
            return entidades.Escopos
                .Where(e => e.CALClientes.Any(cc => cc.IDCALCliente == IDCalCLiente))
                .OrderBy(es => es.IDEscopo)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```